# Show Payment Summary line items on Cognito Forms of $0 values

Tags: cognito-forms

I've been trying out Cognito Forms and I am unable to get the payment summary to show $0.00 values.

For example, in selling cookies, the first cookie is free, but $2 thereafter.

If customer selects only one cookie (therefore free, $0.00), it will still be shown as a line item on the payment summary. Currently $0.00 line items are not reflected onto the payment summary.

I know the moment the price is not $0.00, it'll be shown onto the payment summary as a line item.

Answer (score 1):

For payment forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), zero-dollar line items will only be added for Choice or Yes/No fields with assigned prices of zero.  Price and Currency fields are automatically excluded from the invoice if they are zero dollar, as this is the most common way to prevent unwanted line items from appearing.  Since Price fields always appear on the invoice (even if hidden) this is actually the only way to exclude them.

However, the most common approach to your example is to charge $2.00 per cookie like normal, and then use a Price field to calculate a negative discount, such as: First Cookie Free! - ($2.00).